# Division Tie Breaker - Common Games

Tags: american-football, ranking

I understand the common games tie breaker between division teams but what if Team A has played Team C twice (one loss, one win) and Team B has played Team C only once and won?
Would Team A's pct = .500 while Team B's pct = 1.000 ?
Do I count both games for Team A or only one (and if so, which one?)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify which sport or league you're interested in, but I'm assuming it's the NFL since I know that's a criterion used there.  If that's the case then by the [NFL's tiebreaking procedure](http://www.nfl.com/standings/tiebreakingprocedures), they use the "best won-lost-tied **percentage** in common games."  For your example, Team B would then win the tie-breaker.  I think this makes perfect sense, too, and would expect to see the same method used for any other league that uses this criterion.

Comment: I have another question: What if two teams win their division with the same record, how do they determine who is seeded higher? i.e. Team A wins their division with a 13-3 record, Team B also wins their division with a 13-3 record. How do you determine who is seeded higher in the playoffs?

Comment: From the link in my answer, the first tie-breaker is the head-to-head record against one another.  If, for instance, they have each won and lost one game apiece versus each other, the next tie-breaker is the highest winning percentage against other teams within that division.